# Mysql update two users current balance on click

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple money transfer website, where users can send money to another user and update of both user's current balance. I am a little bit confused. Because I know how to update the balance to the user that sends the money, but unable to update the two of them.

I have 2 tables (users & transactions)

```
TRANSSACTIONS
ID | Sender_WalletID | Receiver_WalletID | Amount | Date_Send

USERS
ID | Email | Password | WalletID | Balance | Total_Earnings | Invoices | Send_Total | Location
```

Currently, I am trying like this

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users 
   SET Balance = $user_new_balance 
 WHERE ID = $getUserId";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Very appreciated for any help

Comment: Well you need 2 queries one for each user, and you should wrap them in a TRANSACTION

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: ...or a transsaction

Comment: I want to make this update when i click a button. So they both can be updated. I cannot like this as mentioned in the Answer down below

Answer (score 0):

For user that send balance it should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Balance=Balance-".$amount." WHERE ID=$userFrom";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

And for user that receive:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Balance=Balance+".$amount." WHERE ID=$userTo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Note the - and + signs (this is to not lose users exiting balance)

I would suggest you to use PDO https://phpdelusions.net/pdo to escape SQL Injections

Comment: I cannot update the same table twice with one connection isn't that right?

Comment: Because i want to do that in one run, on button click

Comment: Why you guess just try it!